# Java: How to reuse listeners

Tags: java, android, listener

I would like to reuse an AlertBuilder and therefore put its creation in an own method. Something like this:

```
private boolean askToDiscardChanges() {

    final boolean result = false;

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    result = true;
                    break;
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    result = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewShootingActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.msgDiscardChanges)).setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.lblYes), dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.lblNo), dialogClickListener).show();

    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work but I hope it helps to understand my issue. Is it possible to return the result of a listener? How?

Thanks

Comment: You are mixing synchronous asynchronous code, that won't work. Just pass the listener as an argument into the `askToDiscardChanges()` method. Alternatively you could implement the listener in the class which contains the `askToDiscardChanges()` method. There are a lot of things you can do here.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I adapted the code:

    askToDiscardChanges(new DiscardCallbackInterface() {

                        @Override
                        public void onUserSelection(boolean result) {
                            if (result == true) {
                                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(NewShootingActivity.this);
                            }
                        }
                    });

Answer (score 3):

A listener is a callback function.  It will be called at some later point in time, possibly far in the future-  or even possibly never.  So no, it can't return a value, because we don't know what to return yet.  If you want to run some code based on a callback being called, you need to put that code in the callback.